# Prevent browser from adding Request header: Connection

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using Angular 1.0, when I am making an XHR call, the "Connection: keep-alive, 'Pragma: no-cache', 'Cache-Control: no-cache'" is added to the request header. How do I prevent it from being added to the XHR request?

What will happen if this header is passed?

Answer (score 0):

you cold config headers on app run

```
module.run(function($http) {
  $http.defaults.headers.common.Connection = '';
});
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#setting-http-headers